# How to call a function in a pyGTK timeout?

Tags: python, pygtk

When I try to call a function using a timeout in pyGtk, I receive the error message `TypeError: second argument not callable`.
All I want to do is call a very simple function from within the time out. To illustrate my proble, I have simply prepared the function `do_nothing` to illustrate my problem.

```
def do_nothing(self):
    return True

# Do interval checks of the timer
def timed_check(self, widget):
    self.check_timing = gobject.timeout_add(500, self.do_nothing())
```

which does not work...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: Find the whole file here: http://pastie.org/1260638

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling the function:

```
self.do_nothing()
```

You want to pass the function:

```
self.do_nothing
```

Omit the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Pass self.do_nothing and not self.do_nothing()

```
self.do_nothing is callable
```

self.do_nothing() returns a value and that return value is not a callable

Answer (score 1):

try instead:

```
self.check_timing = gobject.timeout_add(500, self.do_nothing, self)
```